# How can I create role based testing in Cypress?

Tags: vue.js, cypress

I have a project that needs to be tested via Cypress. I am new in "Cypressing" by the way..

I have problem to find a solution about role-based testing where something like this happen:

> If the xhr response gave a user data with role `admin`, it will redirect to `dashboard/admin`. Otherwise, if the xhr response gave a user data a role `user`, it will redirect to `dashboard/user`.
>
> After that, each views may have different actions & behavior regarding to what kind of user who has logged in.

Please have a look at my script:

```js
const BASE_URL = Cypress.env('BASE_URL')
const APP_NAME = Cypress.env('APP_NAME')
const AUTH_ID = Cypress.env('AUTH_ID')
const PASSWORD = Cypress.env('PASSWORD')

describe('Login Test', () => {
    it('can perform a login action', () => {
        cy.visit(BASE_URL)
        cy.contains(APP_NAME)

        cy.get('input[name="contact"]')
            .type(AUTH_ID)
            .should('have.value', AUTH_ID)

        cy.get('input[name="password"]')
            .type(PASSWORD)
            .should('have.value', PASSWORD)

        cy.get('#submit-button').click()
        cy.url().should('contain', 'dashboard')
    })
})
```

and please have a look at my Vue.js script too:

```html
<template>
  <div id="login">
    <div class="login-card p-4">
      <h1 class="text-center font-weight-bold text-primary py-5">STTKD</h1>

      <!-- phone number input -->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="contact">Nomor Telepon</label>
        <input
          name="contact"
          type="number"
          class="form-control"
          min="0"
          placeholder="08xxx atau 628xxxx"
          v-model="user.contact"
        />
      </div>

      <!-- password-input -->
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password</label>
        <input
          name="password"
          type="password"
          class="form-control"
          placeholder="Masukkan password"
          v-model="user.password"
        />
      </div>

      <div class="form-group text-right">
        <a href="#" class="text-primary">Forgot password?</a>
      </div>

      <!-- login-button -->
      <div class="form-group">
        <button
          id="submit-button"
          type="button"
          class="btn btn-primary btn-block"
          @click="onSubmit"
        >LOGIN</button>
      </div>

      <div class="form-group text-center">
        <p class="mb-0">
          Don't have account?&nbsp;
          <router-link :to="{ name: 'register' }" class="text-primary">Create a new one!</router-link>
        </p>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
  export default {
    data() {
      return {
        user: {
          contact: "",
          password: ""
        }
      };
    },

    methods: {
      onSubmit() {
        axios
          .post("auth/login", this.user)
          .then(resp => {
            VueCookies.set("access_token", resp.data.access_token);
            VueCookies.set("token_type", resp.data.token_type);
            VueCookies.set("expires_at", resp.data.expires_at);

            // redirect with" user" param if the roles array from the response includes "user"
            if (resp.data.user.roles.includes("user")) {
              this.$router.replace({
                name: "dashboard",
                params: {
                  role: "user"
                }
              });
              return;
            }

            // else, redirect with "admin" param
            this.$router.replace({
              name: "dashboard",
              params: {
                role: "admin"
              }
            });
          })
          .catch(err => console.error(err));
      }
    }
  };
</script>
```

As you see above, its running without problem but I have no idea about what to do next because the user behavior is kindof dynamic.

Please help me to solve this problem, any references are good for me if there is.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You know the account you are using in the test so you can crate two different test scenarios. In my opinion it makes not much sense to put much complexity into one test.

Comment: do you mean by testing it per user role?